# Jackson XML mapper attribute serialization issue

Tags: java, xml, jackson

I have next annotated class (serialized into the `<tours>` tag) :

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(
    name = "Tour",
    propOrder = {"restrictions", "result", "wrappedTourPoints"}
)
@JsonTypeInfo(
    use = Id.NAME,
    include = As.PROPERTY,
    property = "$type",
    defaultImpl = Tour.class
)
@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)
public class Tour extends AbstractTour {...}
```

My XmlMapper bean :

```
@Bean
public XmlMapper xmlMapper() {
    JacksonXmlModule module = new JacksonXmlModule();
    module.setDefaultUseWrapper(false);
    XmlMapper xmlMapper = new XmlMapper(module);
    xmlMapper.setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL);
    return xmlMapper;
}
```

After serialization instance of this class into XML using this mapper (`com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.XmlMapper`) I retrieve next XML

```
<TripOptimisationResponse>
    <tourResponses>
        <plan>
            <chains>
                <vehicleId>0</vehicleId>
                <tours
                .type="Tour">
                <startTimeFixed>false</startTimeFixed>
                <id>0</id>
                <tourPointFixation>NONE</tourPointFixation>
                <vehicleFixed>false</vehicleFixed>
                <ignoreIntermediatePeriodOfPreviousTour>false</ignoreIntermediatePeriodOfPreviousTour>
            </tours>
        </chains>
    </plan>
</tourResponses></TripOptimisationResponse>
```

where you can find **.type** attribute.

My question is whether we can change **.type** to **type** (with no dot included)?
Or can we just skip all the attributes in the result XML?

Comment: Have you tried property = "type"?

Comment: @PavelMolchanov, I have no permission to modify code of the class